# how to prevent Concurrent Modification Exception while inserting to lists

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i have to different type of the list that by the methods `categories` and `providers`, I insert Provider and Category type to them. these method get call and receive input from my service class every time i want to add the category or provider to my product. i test it out if i comment one of the `categories` and `providers` it will be fine but with both  of them in the class i have `Concurrent Modification Exception`
I was wondering how can i fix it?

```
    private List<Category> categories;
private List<Provider> providers;

    public void addProvider (Provider p){
        if(providers==null){
            providers=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        providers.add(p);
    }

    public void addCategory (Category cat){
        if(categories==null){
            categories=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        categories.add(cat);

    }
```

this my service method i add it here so you have more clear picture what call `categories` and `providers` methods. product object has a list of the categories and list of the providers.as you can see i am using jpa and springboot for my development

```
   public void saveProduct(Product product){
        Product postProduct=new Product();
        postProduct.setCategories(product.getCategories());
        postProduct.setName(product.getName());
  
       List<Provider> tempo= product.getProviders();
        Provider providerInstans=new Provider();
        for(Provider p: tempo){

            providerInstans.setName(p.getName());
            providerInstans.setId(p.getId());
               Provider po=providerRepository.findByName(providerInstans.getName());
             postProduct.addProvider(po);

        }
        
        List<Category> temp=product.getCategories();
        Category categoryInstance=new Category();
        for(Category i:temp) {
            categoryInstance.setName(i.getName());

            categoryInstance.setId(i.getId());
            // Category a=categoryRepository.findByName("phone");
            String name = categoryInstance.getName();
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println("value" + categoryRepository.findById(1));
            Category a = categoryRepository.findById(1);
           postProduct.addCategory(a);

        }
        productRepository.save(postProduct);
    }
```

Comment: Don't modify the list while traversing it (in your for-each loops). (As a note, it is better to initialize your fields to `new ArrayList<>()` rather than leaving them null and checking in the `add` methods; it is friendlier to code that calls `getProducts` to return empty instead of null.)

Comment: I didn't understand what part of that i need to change. can you please post what part needs to change?

Comment: Use an explicit `Iterator` to iterate over the list, and do the adds via the iterator.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, You assign to `postProduct` already created list by calling

```
postProduct.setCategories(product.getCategories());
```

And then your code:

```
List<Category> temp=product.getCategories();
Category categoryInstance=new Category();
for(Category i:temp) {
    postProduct.addCategory(a);
}
```

Here in for loop `temp` list is the same list, that assigned to the `postProduct` earlier, so you modificate the same list of catefories while iterating over it. Its the error. Not allowed add item in a list, while iterating over it in loop.

Comment: You are allowed to do it, but only via the iterator.

Comment: Bad idea in this case. User think he has two lists, but has two references to the same list. By using iterator user can broke another part of program where list used.

Comment: It may or may not be a bad idea, based on things you don't know anything about in the application, but you are certainly allowed to do it, contrary to what is claimed in your answer.

Comment: Your are right. Iterator is the ideal for changing collection while iteration it via iterator. I just point out to new user his bug. I think his doesn't figure out that accidentally use one reference in to Product instances.